# Why is screen not defined in a program when looped?

Tags: python, pygame

When I try to make a circle at the mouse coordinates, I use this code:

```
def main():
    screen.clear()
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.draw.circle((mx, my), 30, (255, 255, 255))
```

which works *once*, but when I change it to look like this:

```
def main():
    screen.clear()
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.draw.circle((mx, my), 30, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.clear()
while (1):
    main()
```

It raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pgzero/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pgzero/runner.py", line 92, in main
    exec(code, mod.__dict__)
  File "virus-simulation!.py", line 6, in <module>
    main()
  File "virus-simulation!.py", line 2, in main
    screen.clear()
NameError: name 'screen' is not defined
```

Are there any reasons this is happening?

Comment: Where's main ? You may need to add more code to your question to figure out the problem.

Comment: Where is it that you believe `screen` was defined?  There's certainly no definition of it in the code you posted.

Comment: @Mike67 In my Python interpreter the code runs once without explicitly calling `main()`. Maybe I should switch to another interpreter? @jasonharper It seems to be pre-defined. But after the second run, it just... _disappears?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where your screen is being defined, so I can't be sure what's causing the issue. Here is some working code based on your sample. It draws a circle at the mouse position.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

class CDraw():
   def __init__(self, sc): 
       self.scrn = sc
   def circle(self, p, r, c):
       pygame.draw.circle(self.scrn, c, p, r)
       
class CScreen():        
   def __init__(self):
       self.scrn = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
       self.draw = CDraw(self.scrn)
   def clear(self):
       self.scrn.fill((0,200,0))

screen = CScreen()

def main():
    screen.clear()
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.draw.circle((mx, my), 30, (255, 255, 255))
    #screen.clear()  # will remove everything
    for event in pygame.event.get():   # needed for os events
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
    pygame.display.update()  # needed to do screen update
    
while (1):
    main()
```

Comment: I had mentioned in another comment above that it just seems to be defined in the beginning (it draws), but after the initial function run, it doesn't seem to exist anymore (it raises an error)... But thanks for the code anyways!